# Unwanted DB2 timeout when using command chaining

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2

I am using the IBM DB2 driver for .NET with command chaining.

I first open a *DB2Connection* and start a transaction. Then I call *DB2Connection.BeginChain* on my connection to start a bulk insert. I execute a bunch of prepared statements with 0 as the *DB2Command.CommandTimeout*. Last, I call *DB2Connection.EndChain* and commit the transaction.

I expect some of the inserts to fail due to duplicate key errors. I trap this by catching a *DB2Exception* and inspecting the *DB2Exception.Errors* collection. I know which row failed because I can look at the *DB2Error.RowNumber* inside the *Errors* collection.

The problem is that sometimes I trap a *DB2Exception* when I call *DB2Connection.EndChain* and the affected row number is negative.

**[IBM][DB2] SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014**

Searching the DB2 documentation for this error seems to indicate that a query has timed out. I didn't see any information how this relates to chaining. Did the entire chain process time out or was it a problem with an individual query? If the later, then why didn't I get a valid row number? Why am I timing out at all if my *DB2Connection.ConnectionTimeout* is 0 and my *DB2Command.CommandTimeout* is 0?